# How to loop through data-frame columns to obtain statistics

Tags: python, pandas

I need a way to do the following:

- I want to be able to loop through each column in a data-frame that is of the `dtype == object`
- As I am looping through each desired column, I am obtaining the following summary statistics:

  - The name of the attribute
  - The number of unique values each attribute has
  - The most frequently occurring value of each attribute
  - The number of occurrences of the most frequently occurring value
  - The percentage of the total number of values the most frequently occurring value contributes

Say I have the following data:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {"Sex":["M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "F", "F",  "M"],
    "Product": ["X", "Y", "Y", "Z","Y", "Y", "Y", "X", "Z", "Y"],
    "Answer":["Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No",  "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No",  "Yes", "Yes"],
    "Numeric":[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    "Binary":[True, True, False, False, False, True, False, True, True, False]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I need some way to do the following (I know the code isn't correct - hopefully my pseudo-code conveys what I mean)

```
for column in df:
    if df[column].dtype != object:
        continue
    else:
        #pseudo-code begins
        attributes = df[column].name #attribute names
        unique_values = df[column].unique() #number of unique values
        most_frequent = df[column].mode() #most frequently occurring
        occurrences = df[column][most_frequent].nunique() #occurrences of the mode
        proportions = df[column][most_frequent].value_counts(normalize = True) #to get 
        #proportions
```

I then need some way to tabulate all this information into some kind of summary statistics table

```
summaryStats = tabluate([attributes, unique_values, most_frequent, occrrences, proportions])
```

The resulting output should look something like this

```
| Attribute | Unique Values | Mode | Occurrences | % of Total |
|----------- --------------- ------ ------------- ------------|
| Sex          F, M,          F         6             60%     |
| Product      X, Y, Z        Y         7             70%     |
| ...            ...          ...      ...           ...      |

#...and so on and so forth for the other attributes
```

I am essentially creating a summary table for discrete data.

Any help at all would be much appreciated :)

Comment: the pseudo-code demonstrates what you want, but it doesn't explain where you're having trouble. You already know how to construct a dataframe from a dictionary of lists (it's how you construct your example), so it seems like you could put this together pretty easily

Comment: How could loop through a data frame to populate a dictionary whereby the keys of the dictionary are the attribute-names (i.e., the columns of the data frame) and the values are the lists of summary statistics I want?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
data = []

# Loop through columns of dtype `object`
for col in df.select_dtypes("object"):
    # Do a count of each unique value in the column
    freq = df[col].value_counts()

    data.append({
        "Attribute": col,
        # The unique values are the index of the frequency count
        "Unique Values": ", ".join(freq.index.sort_values()),
        # The frequency dataframe is sorted by default, with the most-frequent
        # value appearing first
        "Mode": freq.index[0],
        "Occurrence": freq[0],
        "% of Total": freq[0] / freq.sum() * 100
    })

summary = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: Thank you so much this was a great help! Just another follow up question, how could I change the code so that the "Unique Values" column is not a list of the unique values of the attribute, but rather a count of the unique values?

Comment: Change it to `"Unique Values": len(freq)`

Answer (score 0):

An empty dataframe is created with columns and indexes. The Attribute column is immediately populated with a list. A list aaa is created to substitute its values into loc (line indexes are indicated on the left, column names are on the right). You can read about loc (explicit indexing) [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html?highlight=loc#pandas.DataFrame.loc).

The line that yields 'Unique Values' uses ','.join to concatenate the list into a string. In 'Occurrences' through isin we get a Boolean mask, with which we get all unique values and count. In '% of Total' we extract the first element since the data is sorted and multiply by 100. Also, you should have 6 in Product Occurrences, of course, and % of Total will be different.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(index=[0, 1], columns=['Attribute', 'Unique Values', 'Mode', 'Occurrences', '% of Total'])
df1['Attribute'] = ['Sex', 'Product']
aaa = ['Sex', 'Product']

for i in range(len(aaa)):
    df1.loc[i, 'Unique Values'] = ','.join(df[aaa[i]].unique())
    mod = df[aaa[i]].mode()
    df1.loc[i, 'Mode'] = mod[0]
    df1.loc[i, 'Occurrences'] = df.loc[df[aaa[i]].isin(mod), aaa[i]].count()
    df1.loc[i, '% of Total'] = df[aaa[i]].value_counts(normalize=True)[0] * 100
```

Output

```
  Attribute Unique Values Mode Occurrences % of Total
0       Sex           M,F    F           6       60.0
1   Product         X,Y,Z    Y           6       60.0
```